# Insert data into Firebase at a Preferred location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my Firebase Details:

> Conversations
>
> -KcNOYKbVwSZGqyoD99W
>
> -KcNOeYu1iX6VqVM5tIf
>
> -**KcNPLZdLBva3f2SqspR**
>
> -KcNQlp9H8hxAsS4otxz
>
> -KcOOtlBsMqGhvyrnHS

When I insert data, it adds to the database from below. I need to add the data below `KcNPLZdLBva3f2SqspR` node.

Normally, I use the below code to add data:

```
final DatabaseReference imageref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Message").child(data_contact.get(position).getChatadd()).child("Conversations");
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
final String temp_key = imageref.push().getKey();
imageref.updateChildren(map);

DatabaseReference message_roottemp = imageref.child(temp_key);

Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map2.put("Text", "Ouch..");
map2.put("sender_name", data_contact.get(position).getCurrent_user());
map2.put("sender_photo", "");
map2.put("timestamp", mydate);
map2.put("message_status", "Saved");
map2.put("msg_type", "POKE");
message_roottemp.updateChildren(map2);
```

What modifications are needed to add data below a required node?

My Use-Case is: Say at `KcNPLZdLBva3f2SqspR` node, an Image URL is there. The user comments to this image. So I need to post the data below this node, as when I load data into a RecyclerView. The image and comment shows one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about adding below another position and as i have seen data is added in a sorted manner(i am not sure so please confirm).

But i can give you a better solution to the problem.

**You should probably create a child attribute in your database for properties of each image.**

> For Example : I had the same type of situation. So i created an entry
>   for each new image in my database with random name. Then after
>   fetching that name from your database upload the image with the same
>   name in your firebase storage.

And there you have it. No matter how many comments you upload for your image, you can always fetch that entry from your database where you are keeping all your image attributes.

I know that this is not what your question was but it is a solution to your problem. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks For Your ans... I have Opted for the same ....I Found No Solution So had To Go With That Implementation...
say >> KcNPLZdLBva3f2SqspR >> make a Child Node containing all Comments.....I Thought of this Implementation but Was Thinking about alternative Solutions

Comment: Its okay. In my opinion its the best solution. You can't rely on the sequence that much.